# Trouble when creating token for Buildspace core 5 final exercise

Tags: metaplex-js

I'm trying to finish the final exercise of Buildspace Core 5 (here https://buildspace.so/p/solana-core/lessons/building-the-front-end ), but now when I try to regenerate the token using the frontend helper tokens/bld/index.ts I get the error:

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/home/srmq/devel/solana-nas/buildoor/node modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5860:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/home/srmq/devel/solana-nas/buildoor/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5819:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/home/srmq/devel/solana-nas/buildoor/node modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5807:12)
    at async Object.sendAndConfirmTransaction (/home/srmq/devel/solana-nas/buildoor/node modules/@solana/web3.js/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:35:21) {
  logs: [
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Error: BorshIoError',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 3805 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown'
  ]
}
```

It is just a straightforward token generation from Javascript code, it used to work before, I don't understand why it stopped working. This frontend code is at https://github.com/srmq/buildoor (more specifically https://github.com/srmq/buildoor/blob/main/tokens/bld/index.ts) while the corresponding backend is at https://github.com/srmq/anchor-nft-staking (but I don't think the backend is relevant for this problem)

Any ideas?

Yours,

Sergio

Comment: please how you found a way out, I am encoutering the exact same error

Answer (score 2):

the instruction

import {
DataV2,
createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

does not exist anymore because, metaplex removed it in an attempt to save space in their program. So you need to use createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction.
Maybe write the creators of the course to update.

Here is a similar question: [create_metadata_account_v2 is gone what should I do?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6578/create-metadata-account-v2-is-gone-what-should-i-do)