# create_metadata_account_v2 is gone what should I do?

Tags: metaplex

create_metadata_account_v2 is not available anymore.

Now I can not run my anchor tests because anchor-spl relies on create_metadata_account_v2. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

metaplex recently had to remove a bunch of old deprecated instructions to free up space in their program:
See anouncement here: https://twitter.com/MetaplexStatus/status/1631464812361424897?s=20

Affected instructions are:

- create_metadata_account
- create_metadata_account_v2
- update_metadata_account

So in your client you need to upgrade in your package.json to for example:

```
"@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^2.11.0",
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.3.7"
```

and if you are using Anchor, they built a fix last week, but it is not released yet, so you can point directly to the master branch like this in your cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { git = "https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor", features = 
["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = { git = "https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor", features = 
["metadata"] }
bytemuck = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["derive", 
"min_const_generics"]}
```

See the changelog of anchor here: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md